# Azure Website Connection Keep-Alive

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service, keep-alive

I was using Windows Azure Website to host my website.

1. I want to enable `Connection: Keep-Alive` in my website, how to enable it  for my website?
2. How to check whether I have successfully enabled it on my website?
3. How to set the `timeout` for the `Connection: Keep-Alive` and how to determine the best value for the `timeout`

My server is Windows and using IIS

Comment: Is your server windows or linux?

Comment: @SharenEayrs, my server is Windows

Comment: For Azure Cloud Services and VMs it looks like [this is configurable](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/08/14/new-configurable-idle-timeout-for-azure-load-balancer/). I haven't found an answer for Azure Websites/WebApps yet.

Answer (score 8):

You can set most of the configuration options for IIS 8 in Azure Web Sites too. To enable keep-alive, add the following section in the web.config

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol allowKeepAlive="true" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I assume it is the same way.
On Azure WebSites a web.config file is automatically created. Go thorough Kudo to find the web.config file and modify it (remember to allow edit in Visual Studio Steam Services setting)

Comment: I added that config, restarted my app and don't see keep alive in the response header of my queries (I also tried to request it in my request headers).