# How to enable Connection:Keep-Alive for ASP.NET Core 2.1

Tags: asp.net, azure, keep-alive

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.1 website running on a windows server as an azure web app. I was asked to enable "keep-alive" so that when a client asks for "Connection:Keep-Alive" the connection is NOT closed. I cant find any documentation on how to do this (nor if this is even possible).

The reason for getting a persistent connection (if this is the correct term) is to reduce the overhead from the SSL negotiation.

I did find this: [Azure Website Connection Keep-Alive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28085768/azure-website-connection-keep-alive) stack-overflow question. The provided answer doesn't help. There is no web.config file in ASP.NET Core web apps. I didn't find anything else regarding Keep-Alive in ASP.NET Core.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, there will still be a web.config file for IIS in web app. After you publish your .NET Core web app, you can use Azure Kudu tools from portal to checks files, and you will find the web.config generated by system.

[image]

So, you can manually add a web.config file in your project:

[image]

And then choose web configuration file

[image]

Then, you can add your configurations:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol allowKeepAlive="true" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Finally, deploy your project, and configurations will be updated in kudu:

[image]

Comment: I have set the mentioned setting in config file and deployed the same in IIS 8.5, but no luck. Is there any other way to make this work ?